# How to get an Amazon.com type navigation bar (seemingly two navbars wrapped within a single container)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want to get the above type of navbar.
What I tried was this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <!-- Some stuff like the brand image, search box etc. -->
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <!-- The main navigation stuff -->
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

but this makes something like this...
[image]

How can I remove those gaps without modifying bootstrap.css

Comment: You may want to review the documentation on navbar as you're declairing three navbars here two inside another. Add a class to the top navbar, like top-navbar and then add the style .top-navbar { margin-bottom: 0px; } to a stylesheet (Do not change the bootstrap css)

Comment: Thanks. Seems to do it. Any advantages to using inline styles (<style> tags within the file) over custom.css files that I will have to include?

Comment: Browsers are able to download multiple resources at the same time and processes them at the same time. If you include all styling in your page you'll not be able to reuse the same styling over multiple pages and browsers will not be able to cache the content of the stylesheet. Separate style sheets save time, bandwidth and improve re-usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navbar-class has margin-bottom: 20px in bootstrap.css so you need to make an overriding rule there.

But rather than making the rule change to the bootstrap.css file, make another CSS file, eg. custom.css, where you write these new rules. Add this file to your html template after the bootstrap.css and it will override the basic rules.

Make always the new CSS rules to the custom.css, it's much easier to handle.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to do it. Also, should I just declare the CSS inline using <style>. Any disadvantages of doing it? I am asking this because this custom CSS will only be used in a single php file (which will in turn be included by other pages needing it)

Comment: I guess that since you're building a site from a scratch(?) you'll be writing alot more CSS-styles for the site and you should put all of them to the same custom.css file instead of inline. Or if you have some other CSS file for your own styles. It works as long it's loaded after the bootstrap.css